# Piece of old "kiswa" (black cloth of kaba) hanging at home

Tags: halal-haram, belief, kaabah

Assalamualaikum,

One of my relatives kept a piece of kiswa of kaba at home. And whenever they are going to do something big/good like before going to abroad, before marriage, before an interview, etc. they make dua to Allah in front of the framed piece of kiswa.
Is it okay/ allowed in islam?

Jazakallah khayer.

Answer (score 2):

Assalam-o-alikum. According to Wikipedia at the time of Umar rad-e-yallah hu, old kiswa was cut into pieces and given to hujaj. Hujaj then used it to shelter from heat like umbrella. Their is no proof that it has any significance in Islam. Indeed it raises doubt in the believer heart, and one should avoid it. You can keep it as an antique but not a blessed item. 
Umar rad-e-yallah once heard addressing to the hajer Aswad "if I have not seen  Rasoolullah Swallah alay he wa salam kissing you, I would never kissed you as I knew that you are just a stone which can't benefits nor give harm to anyone".

This statement of Umar rad-e-yallah clearly indicated that hajer Aswad can't do anything to anyone, which is part of the wall of Kaaba then how the kiswa piece will do.

May Allah give guidance to each and everyone of us.Ameen.

Answer (score 0):

Any piece of kaaba is mubbarak.

Behold, the first Temple ever set up for mankind was indeed the one at Bakkah: rich in blessing, and a [source of] guidance unto all the worlds,

It s in the quran. 3:96

A great 3alim told me that if you keep a part of the kiswa you have to cover it and you need a great adab.

Because it s like you are in a Moubarak place.

Allah knows best

Comment: Please add a reference to the statement or to support the statement from the great alim.